# How to know all HTTP requests sendable by an Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, api

Is It possible generating a sort of documentation,
where are addressed all HTTP requests sendable by a specific Angular Application?

Answer (score 0):

try to store the url addresses into an array and then loop the HTTP request call.
Something like this maybe:

```js
for (var i=0 ; i < $scope.urls.length ; i++)
{
  $http.get($scope.urls[i])
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.results[i] = response.data;
        })
        .error(function(response){
            $scope.errors[i] = response.error;
            $scope.errormessages[i] = response.errormessage;
        });
}
```

And using scope.$evalAsync(function () {}) if needed to synchronous the call.

Comment: I don't need to track responses but just all end-points with the params, touched by the Angular application

Comment: No I think, since angularjs is only a client side scripting that must know the endpoint before invoking it.